# Receive information into PHP from Flash

Tags: php, flash, security

I have a Flash game, and I want to save the winner's name in the database. To do so, I send the name and the points to a PHP file. I know to do this, and receive the information through the PHP GET variables.

```
scores.php?winner=name&points=5034
```

It will work fine as I see. but there is one problem that I thought of. What if someone just launch into the PHP file manually?

Comment: Check this answer you can use s POST http://stackoverflow.com/a/6876800/1551411

Comment: What version of Actionscript are you using? If I were writting this I would not pass the variables through the URL. I would use a POST directly from flash. IMO this would be much safer. Another option would be to use `ExternalInterface.call()` in Flash to some Javascript (jQuery) to post the information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't you use encryption method to encrypt data and send them. Read [this article](http://flashcodetips.blogspot.com/2011/07/low-level-string-encryption-using-php.html) for more info. Decrypt when you get the values and store them in the database. Else you can use POST method. [read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876588/sending-and-receiving-data-from-flash-as3-to-php/6876800#6876800)