# How to set up a MYSQL database that communicates with flash?

Tags: php, mysql, database, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to set up a MYSQL database on my shared hosting account for use with a Flash game and am having a bit of trouble understanding how to do this. How would I communicate 4 variables (1 username, and three variables associated with that username) from the Flash game to my web server?

From what I understand, I think I'll want to pass the info from Flash to a PHP script, which will then pass it to my database. But I'm very new to all this and can't find any tutorials about how to even set up the server properly, let alone how to handle the variables that are sent from Flash in the PHP script.

Am I on the right track? Any useful tutorials would be really appreciated

Comment: The reason you aren't finding anything is that you are looking for a full solution.  Instead, look up how to POST data to PHP.  And then, follow any PHP database tutorial.  Also, make sure whatever tutorial you use utilizes PDO (or similar) with prepared/parameterized queries.  If it doesn't, you're learning the wrong methods for using a database.

Comment: Thanks! Just found this [tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876588/sending-and-receiving-data-from-flash-as3-to-php) for communicating with Flash to PHP and now I'm off to go find one for communicating those PHP variables to my MYSQL database.