# Packaging files for iOs development in adobe air application

Tags: php, ios, mysql, flash

I'm working on a simple iOs APP in *adobe Flash CS6 AIR application*. the app would have a `registration and Login` form which communicate with **MYSQL** database on my server using **PHP** and Flash (well flash wont be flash once its packaged as iOs).

now the question that i have its confusing me alot is that do i need to include the PHP files when i package the APP in flash?

its all a bit confusing because on the normal server/domain all you do is place the Flash file and PHP in the same directory or folder on the same server and it would work but on an iPhone APP, there is no server and I'm not sure how the MYSQL connection in php would work!

could someone please shed a light on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876588/sending-and-receiving-data-from-flash-as3-to-php

Comment: @Craig, my question is not about how to communicate from flash and php! its actually about how to package my stuff in AIR application. thanks

Comment: Well, after reading your original post AND your answer to my comment I  STILL don't really understand what you want. Maybe you could ask a clearer question?

Comment: @Craig, which part of my question is un-clear?! or actually what I should say is which part of my question indicates that I cannot get Flash and PHP to communicate?!? you didn't answer my question anyway! you just commented on it... ;) I clearly stated that i need to know information about packaging iOs app created in flash and including the files in the package!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your iOS application.  You only need to include the files are that going to be directly running on the device (ie. additional SWC's and images).  The PHP file since it is going to be accessed elsewhere will not be required to be added.  Also just a word of device, make sure to compile the iOS application with the most recent Version of AIR, or Apple will reject it.