# How to edit a text field directly from as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am designing an app and basically I want the user to fill in text field directly from the app and then I want this textfield to be saved in a text file inside a server ? How can I do it ?
Right now I can Only view the text file but I can't really edit it . 
Thanks for answers.

Comment: What is the nature of the server? You've tagged your question with AIR, so do you just want to save the text locally or actually send it to the cloud somewhere?

Comment: I want to send it to the cloud

Comment: For the text, you just need to set your text field as `Input Text` from the properties panel in flash.     To send the text, most people use `URLRequest`.

Comment: OK I done the input text field part but how do I use URL request

Comment: I want it to edit a text file (.txt) already on the server.

Comment: Here is the documentation for [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#).   When you load, you pass in a [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) and set the `data` property to the text you want to send to the server

Comment: As far as the server part goes, that is largely dependent on the technology and programming languages used on your server.

Comment: What do you mean about that?

Comment: I mean that it has nothing to do with Flash or AS3.   Does your server use PHP?   .NET?   JSP?   The answer will be very different depending on the answer.

Comment: It uses php does that make a difference?

Comment: The web is chock full of examples on how to send data from Flash/AIR to PHP,  and how to read/write/append text files in PHP.      Here is an example of the AS3 side of things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876588/sending-and-receiving-data-from-flash-as3-to-php

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis One more question , do i need a cross domain file to access files inside of my server in air apps ? Thanks again

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis and the comment sections of this tag are full of what should have been answers or close votes. If you found a duplicate, please mark it as such.

Comment: @Asta: please only ask one question per question and don't ask new questions in comments. If you need a cross-pollination out not should be asked in a new question, **however** there are a ton of questions about that already, too. Do your research first and only ask a new question if the existing ones do not help you. Thanks.